# How do I filter Batchpayments basis the InvoiceId?

Tags: xero-api

I am able to verify InvoiceID for a particular Invoice in Batchpayment. Using following filter,
where=Payments[0].Invoice.InvoiceID==Guid("b55b2deb-8bd7-46b9-9965-2a20ed3ae555")

But, not able to filter throughout the array. Tried using following syntax,
where=Payments[*].Invoice.InvoiceID==Guid("b55b2deb-8bd7-46b9-9965-2a20ed3ae555")

Answer (score 0):

This may be something you want to filter after the full response is delivered from the API. That may be easier than structuring the API call to filter only the desired results in this scenario.

- How are you making these API calls?
- What is your end goal? Get all payments for a specific invoice?

If you can include the SDK or a bit more about your use case I can try to help you figure out the best way to achieve your intended goals.